# DependencyResolver and Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some code working fine usind a Dependency Resolver and my WebAPI controller. (We don't use any proper DI solution yet, its very much 'poor mans di' here.)

so in my web resolver I have;

```
  public object GetService(Type serviceType)
  {
    return serviceType == typeof(MyAPIController) ? new MyAPIController() : null;
  }
```

And my WebAPi.Config is;

```
{
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
  config.DependencyResolver = new MyDependencyResolver();
}
```

That works fine.

I am not trying to implement logging, and rather than doing it in the controller I am trying to do it in a logging controller using a decorator, so I have;

```
public class MyLoggingController : ApiController, IMyController
{
    readonly ILogger _log;
    IMyController _controller;

...  other methods + constructor left out for brevity     

[Route("api/GetVersion/v1/")]
    [HttpGet]
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVersion()
    {
        try
        {         
            _log.TraceAPI("MyLoggingController", "MyLoggingController.GetVersion");

            var response = _controller.GetVersion();
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
...omitted for brevity
        }
    }
```

And in the DependencyResolver

```
   public object GetService(Type serviceType)
   {
       return serviceType == typeof(IMyController) ? new MyLoggingController(_log, new MyController()) : null;
   }
```

All that preamble aside, when I now browse to my url I get an error. I suspect that the issue is simply my routing config as it doesn't find the APIController and defauts to the standard ControllerFactory class I have. (Where it crashes as ControllerFactory returns IController not ApiController)

So if I am correct, how do I change my route so that the url doesn't change, but it hits the dependency resolver asking for the correct class(es).

Comment: I would advise you to setup proper DI with something like Unity, Structuremap, AutoFac or LightInject first. Then test it out, because your "poor mans" isn't poor, it just won't work...

Comment: I am constrained with what I can use. The error is that the resolver isn't called because the route doesn't match, so the routing falls down to the Controller Factory. I don't think that changing the way we do DI will affect this, I suspect its purely a routing issue, and I need to make a route that will map a route for XController to LoggingXController, though without having to change the url. My other option is to see if I can get some kind of aspect oriented framework approved and do the logging that way. (Or break solid and have my class logging and doing work)

Comment: The dependency resolver class is so that you can hook in a DI framework such as Structuremap etc... By trying to roll out your own you're just reinventing the wheel for no reason. I don't understand how you're constrained with what you can use, it is DI, use nuget, configure it and away you go....

Comment: Right now its time, and the delay it will take getting agreement to use any new 3rd party libraries. However we are (I think) getting off the point of my question. right now I think the issue is my routing, as I want to call the method via LoggingMyController, but still have the route mapped to /MyController

Comment: what is the url you call? Your `DependencyResolver` will only work for one controller.... thus is pretty useless....

Comment: yeah, after my last comment I realsied I needed to take a step back. Right now this project needs WebAPI and normal controllers. I assume that if I install a DI container for evaluation whilst going through the 'getting it approved' process, it will support both types of controller in one place?